# Managing languages array in single field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a form which manage languages with their alias in the database.
The form looks like:

```
<label for="Setting2Value">Languages</label>
<input name="data[Setting][2][value]" type="text" value="{"English":"eng","Russian":"rus"}" rel="" id="Setting2Value" />
```

And I need some more user friendly interface to be able to add/delete/edit languages in this single field.

Comment: I can't imagine that works the way you want it to as shown.

Comment: seriously, what is that? Are you trying to mix in some templating system in there?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use select

```
<select name="data[settting][2][value]" id = "Setting2Value">
    <option value="eng">English</option>
    <option value="rus">Russan</option>
</select>
```

To add a option:

```
$('<option value="ita">Italy</option>').appendTo("select#Setting2Value");
```

To remove a option

```
$("option[value="eng"]').remove()
```

more object-oriented way would be creating a class to manage this

Comment: I dont need to select options but just to edit this field in userfriendly way and to keep it as input text.
Probably what i need it to have a jquery function which to decode the input text field value and to display it as a list with language name and language alias, button delete for each language and one button at the bottom to add new language. And to updates the input text value.